# pg_stat_statements_reset() schedule

Tags: sql, postgresql, scheduled-tasks, amazon-aurora, pg-stat-statements

Aurora Postgres 11.8

Is there any way possible that a non-superadmin user can run pg_stat_statements_reset()?

Details:

Have to schedule pg_stat_statements_reset() on an hourly basis, since there is no internal scheduler available in Aurora Postgres 11.8, I want to go for lambda/cronjob as only the superadmin can run it so its a security risk in my environment to expose superadmin password in a lambda/cronjob. So is there any way out in my case? can there be an sp that starts execution from non-superuser and then switch user within etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The **documentation** for [`pg_stat_statements_reset`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/pgstatstatements.html#id-1.11.7.38.7.2.1.1.2) says:

> `pg_stat_statements_reset` discards statistics gathered so far by `pg_stat_statements` corresponding to the specified `userid`, `dbid` and `queryid`. If any of the parameters are not specified, the default value `0`(invalid) is used for each of them and the statistics that match with other parameters will be reset. If no parameter is specified or all the specified parameters are `0`(invalid), it will discard all statistics. **By default, this function can only be executed by superusers. Access may be granted to others using GRANT.**

*Let me repeat that:* **Access may be granted to others using `GRANT`.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, didn't work for me.
doc you refer to is of v13, I am working on v11 that don't have any parameter with said function.
Moreover, I have granted the following to my user but still got permission denied error

GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION public.pg_stat_statements_reset() TO my_user;
GRANT ALL ON FUNCTION public.pg_stat_statements_reset() TO my_user;

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name I'm quoting the text of a specific version of the documentation (version 13, currently the latest). In the future, the `current` version of the document may say something different, so I deliberately linked to the version I'm quoting. Reverted your change.